# setstreetview doesn't put any impact on my map view, i want to get hybrid view

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-api-3, google-api

`mapView.setStreetView(true);` doesn't make any impact on the map view of my app, instead when i 
write `mapView.setStreetView(true);` a line is marked over it. If any body could tell me what actually is this function for and `setTraffic` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement street view like this when you set the mapView.setStreetView(true);

```
private void showStreetView(){
    String geoUriString = "google.streetview:cbll="+latitude+","+longitude+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21";  
    Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);  
    Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);  
    startActivity(mapCall);
}
```

and for traffic no need any thing like this but traffic layer work for some countries like new york, canada, etc.

Comment: well pratik, i did like this: mapView.setStreetView(true); String geoUriString = "google.streetview:cbll="+latitude+","+longitude+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21";  
    Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);  
    Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);  
    startActivity(mapCall);    But only black screen is displayed and nothing else

Comment: well this also be not implemented for all country try to pass America country lat/lng value

Comment: kindly tell me that shall i put lat/lng in degrees minutes seconds value or float value

Comment: float value for e.g. 39.295765945,-98.61328125

Comment: yup it worked, and kindly tell me how to implement hybrid map view, suggest me some website which gives float values for lat and lng

Comment: you can implement this by user interface like first get the user point on map and get the location point the provide the button, so when user click on button you can call this code from "String geoUriString..." to last but first check whether is street view is enable or not